# Adding Woocommerce categories below the shop images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was working on adding the product categories to under the shop image on my site.  I have it working using the code below, but the categories do not have spaces between them. I am a bit of a novice here so wondered if someone can help me where I could add a space of comma between each category listing that would be great!  Thanks in advance.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'after_shop_loop_item_title', 1 );

function after_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'videocategories' ); 
  $text = "<h3>Category: ";

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $text .= $term->name;
    }
    $text .= "</h3>";
    echo $text;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP `implode()` function. This will create a string from an array and separate them with a separator of your choosing.

In the example below I first created an array of the categories and then used the `implode()` function in combination with the `printf()` function to print a comma separated list enclosed by `h3` tags:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'after_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );
function after_shop_loop_item_title() {

    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'videocategories' ); 
    $product_cats = array();

    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        // Get an array of the categories
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            $product_cats[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_term_link( $term->slug, 'videocategories' ), $term->name );
        }
        // Convert product category array into comma separated string
        printf( '<h3>Category: %s</h3>', implode( ', ', $product_cats ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great!!  Have a great day, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: Hi again! Is it possible to easily add in a link to the category in the above code too so that it would be clickable and show you all the products with that category attached?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, see updated answer. (Not tested but should work.)

Comment: No problem. If you like you can upvote the answer too.